# Updating SQL Table for a temptable

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I have a SQL table that gets all the data from a temptable. I would like to add a column into the temp table. How can i update my sql table? Thanks.

ps: #Sonuc is my temp table and ANALIZ.dbo.HizliSatanOptionRaporu2_v1 is permanent.

```
select hr.STORECODE,
        s.StoreDescription,
        s.StoreAtt04 AVMCadde,
        s.StoreAtt05 SezonOutlet,
        s.StoreAtt06 SesGrup,
        s.StoreAtt07 Brands,
        s.StoreAtt25 MeteorYaz,
        s.StoreAtt26 MeteorKis,
        s.StoreAtt27 StoreGrade,
        s.StoreAtt28 MusteriProfili,
        s.CityDescription Sehir,
        s.StateDescription Bolge,
       Division,
       Department,
       SubDepartment,
       Category,
       Class,
       ItemCode,
       ColorCode,
       LEFT(ItemCode,2) Sezon,
       ItemCode+ColorCode [Option],
       ToplamStok,
       ToplamSatis,
       case when ToplamSatis=0 then 0 else 1 end SatisVarMi,
       SDH,
       Att_Basic,
       BasicOlmaDurumu,
       Sorun,
       hr.ProductHierarchyID,
       GETDATE() as SonGuncellemeTarihi 
       into #Sonuc
      from #HiyerarsiID hr 
      join ANALIZ.dbo.tb_ProductHierarchy ph on hr.ProductHierarchyID = ph.ProductHierarchyID
      inner join ANALIZ.dbo.gg_StoreInfo s on s.StoreCode=hr.StoreCode


select * 
into ANALIZ.dbo.HizliSatanOptionRaporu2_v1
from #Sonuc
```

Comment: Please post what you already tried and the SQL statement you're using to update your `SQL table`

Comment: What you really need here is a complete question. We have no idea what you are trying to do here at all because you haven't provided enough details. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange As my question has been answered below, i believe that i have already provided enough details. Thanks for suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do  it like a normal table.

alter table #tempTable
add column int

Comment: I have already added the column into the tempTable and there is no problem with that. My question is how can i update the permanent table after updating tempTable?

Comment: with you want to update te permanent table with data from the temp just make a update with join

update a
    set columnA = ColumnB
  from permanente a
  join temp             b on b.idA = a.id